# Performing date QC in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a study_id variable, diagnosis (date_diagnosis), and ten appointment dates (appointment1, appointment2, etc.). I'd like to perform QC on the dataframe to confirm that the date of birth occurred PRIOR to the appointment dates. I considered using a logical variable which would be TRUE if the dob is incorrectly AFTER the appointment dates for ANY of the appointments. I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(incorrect_dob = pmap_lgl(select(., starts_with("appointment")), ~any(.x < dob)))
```

Please see attached sample data where the first two rows should violate the rule and generate a TRUE in the variable we create. Any suggestions? Also, any ideas why the first bit of code didn't work?

```
#set seed

set.seed(122)

# Create a function to generate random dates
random_dates <- function(n, start_date, end_date) {
  as.Date(start_date) + floor(runif(n, min = 0, max = as.integer(end_date - start_date)))
}

# Define start and end dates
start_date <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-12-31")

df <- tibble(
  study_id = 1:5,
  date_birth = random_dates(5, as.Date("1995-01-01"), as.Date("2002-01-01")),
  appointment1 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment2 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment3 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment4 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment5 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment6 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment7 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment8 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment9 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date),
  appointment10 = random_dates(5, start_date, end_date)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but one base R way to flag violations would be to use `sapply` and `rowSums`:

```
cols <- grep("appointment", colnames(df))

rowSums(sapply(cols, 
               function(x) (df[,"date_birth"] - df[,x]) > 0))
# [1] 1 1 0 0 0

#or 
as.logical(rowSums(sapply(cols, 
                          function(x) (df[,"date_birth"] - df[,x]) > 0)))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You can create a new column flagging it (here using the 1/0 approach as an example, sam for the boolean T/F though):

```
df$violation <- rowSums(sapply(cols, 
                               function(x) (df[,"date_birth"] - df[,x]) > 0))
```

If you wanted to isolate IDs with an issue:

```
df[df$violation == 1, "study_id"]
  # or with boolean TRUE/FALSE
df[df$violation, "study_id"]

  study_id
     <int>
1        1
2        2
```